# ReportViewer: Show reports in Print Layout with Page Width zoomMode

Tags: c#-3.0, reportviewer, report-viewer2010, reportviewer2008

I am using C# winform reportviewer 2010.

I changed the default option to view reports to Print Layout (Whole page) with SetDisplayMode(). However since Whole Page is the default zoom option for print layout, even if I set the ZoomMode to PageWidth in the designer,when the report loads, it resets to Whole page. Is it possible to programatically set the ZoomMode to Page width after setting the displayMode?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can do like this:

1. Fill all report parameters
2. Then you refresh your report in order to show your data

   `myReport.RefreshReport();`
3. Finally set this properties

   `myReport.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent;
   myReport.ZoomPercent = 100;`

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 6):

reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout);

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, I figured zoomMode could be set this way:

this.reportViewer1.ZoomMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ZoomMode.PageWidth;

Answer (score 1):

After refresh your rdlc report write

```
my_Report.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.PageWidth;
my_Report.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;
my_Report.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent;
```

Answer (score 0):

**After**
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
**you can add**

reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
reportViewer1.ZoomMode=ZoomMode.PageWidth;